# Ansible loop task with dynamic variable

Tags: loops, variables, ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like set DNS Primary Addresses on hosts dynamicly with Ansible.
The host group underneath should be extandable with X hosts and should still go on with this "dns entry loop" (see the list underneath).

I have the following Servers in my Ansible inventory:

```
[yst-ad-server]
server1
server2
server3
```

I want to set the DNS entrys for this servers like this:

```
Server:     Primary DNS:
server1 --> server3
server2 --> server1
server3 --> server2
```

---

Without loops my task is working and looks like this:

```
- name: Select all AD Servers (but the first in group) and set their DNS server to the first server in group (usually the master)
  win_dns_client:
    adapter_names: '*'
    ipv4_addresses: "{{ hostvars[groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'][-1]].ansible_host }}"
  when: inventory_hostname == groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'][0]
```

(Environment_Name is a var I set while running the playbook. In this case I would use "-e environemnt_name=yst" to match with the inventory group mentioned above.) 
This part gets the IP of server3 (last in group, so I use -1) and set it on the first host (0) in group, which is server1 when the hostname of the current host matches.

After some researches and tests, I am now at this point:

```
- name: name
  win_dns_client:
    adapter_names: '*'
    ipv4_addresses: "{{ hostvars[groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'][item]].ansible_host }}"
  when: inventory_hostname == groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'][item + 1]
  loop: "{{ range(-1, 3)|list }}"
```

Unfortunately this does not work.
The error i get is:

```
The conditional check 'inventory_hostname == groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'][item + 1]' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (inventory_hostname == groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'][item + 1]): list object has no element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range has one too many positive elements: index 3 does not exist

Since you want to support X number of servers, rather than fixing the hardcoded value, create your range dynamically for the number of servers present in your group

`range( -1, groups[environment_name + '-ad-server'] | length -1 ) | list`

Comment: Oh now I see it, I interpreted the error in a wrong way. Thanks for your help!
Since I changed the range to your suggestion, it works.